# Atlassian Confluence with external SQL Database 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, confluence

I want to use a external database for Atlassian Confluence.
Therefore i´ve installed a SQL Server 2008 Express. 
Confluence and the sql server are on the same machine (just a virtuell atm.)

I started the confluence wizard to use a external database, but now im stuck at the step 2. (Configure Database).

But I dont know exactly what I should type in these spaces.

[image]

What did they mean with Password and User name?
The user name and password of the server instance or for the single database?

I tried to connect like this:

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/confluence
User Name: WIN-2008STD/Administrator
Passwort:

but then I got this error:

> Configuring the database failed. Couldn't create the database schema.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused:
>   connect

---

Information bout my SQL Server:

Server name: WIN-2008STD\SQLEXPRESS

Database which should be used by confluence : confluence

IP Adress : 192.168.1.106

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a user within SQL Server who has appropriate access to the database "confluence"?

You need to supply the user name and password of this user in the screenshot you supplied.

The Database URL  should include the name of the database - "confluence" - you are trying to connect to, i.e.:

- jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/confluence

You may want to look at [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961) for managing your SQL Server - you should be able to create the user and grant appropriate access also.

Also worthwhile reviewing the notes within the [Atlassian documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Database+Setup+for+SQL+Server) for connecting Confluence to SQL Server.

Comment: Well , now I have created a new sql user named confluence. This user seems to work, but I still get no connection. I tried //localhost:1433/confluence //192.168.1.106:1433/confluence //127.0.0.1:1433/confluence  always the same error. The documentation of atlassian couldnt help too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the instance details for SQLExpress. You would need something like `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/confluence;instance=SQLEXPRESS`